# Why doesn't Django's CSRF work over HTTPS?

Tags: django, https, django-csrf

I have a Django website at http://example.com that works fine, including post requests. I've added HTTPS so my site is accessible at https://example.com too.

I can load any page on HTTPS, but I always get CSRF validation errors when I try to POST. POST requests work fine on HTTP.

My Django process is running with gunicorn behind nginx, and I have nginx setting `X_Forwarded_For`. So, an HTTPS request has the following headers (taken from `request.META`):

```
'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
'HTTP_COOKIE': 'redacted',
'HTTP_HOST': 'example.com:80',
'HTTP_REFERER': 'https://example.com/user/delete/49/',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '1.2.3.4, 192.168.252.22',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'https',
'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '1.2.3.4',
```

and an HTTP request has the following headers:

```
'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
'HTTP_COOKIE': 'redacted',
'HTTP_HOST': 'example.com.com:80',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '1.2.3.4, 192.168.252.22',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',
'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '1.2.3.4',
```

Why doesn't CSRF work on HTTPS when I have no problems over HTTP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out it was an nginx configuration issue. My server setup is:

nginx -> nginx -> gunicorn

On the second nginx system, I had

```
proxy_set_header        Host            $host:$server_port;
```

However, since HTTPS is terminated at the first nginx, `$server_port` was always 80.

On HTTPS, [Django does strict referer checking](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works) (see point 4). Looking at the Django source:

```
good_referer = 'https://%s/' % request.get_host()
if not same_origin(referer, good_referer):
    reason = REASON_BAD_REFERER % (referer, good_referer)
    logger.warning('Forbidden (%s): %s', reason, request.path,
        extra={
            'status_code': 403,
            'request': request,
        }
    )
    return self._reject(request, reason)
```

CSRF validation was failing because `"https://example.com/" != "https://example.com:80/"`.

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: it's awesome :D

Comment: I met the same problem which error message is `CSRF Failed: Referer checking failed - https://example.com:port/ does not match any trusted origins.`.  My simple solution is setting CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['example.com:port']

Comment: I solved it copying config from https://mattsegal.dev/nginx-django-reverse-proxy-config.html

Answer (score 4):

Like mentioned [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/django-behind-a-proxy-fixing-absolute-urls) I solved this problem by adding the following Django constants in `settings.py` so Django considers proxy headers:

```
# Setup support for proxy headers
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` setting is wrong - change it to:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['similarchords.com', 'www.similarchords.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a public host with HTTPS but the internal host was HTTP so forwarding `https://myhost.com/path/` to `http://internal-host.myhost.com/path` failed. Here is how the config was:

```
location @proxy_to_app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # the following means the $scheme e.g. https is forwarded
    # disabling this fixes the problem
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://domain name',
    
]

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Answer (score -2):

If you look at the implementation of 
[CsrfViewMiddleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py)

Django checks for 'Referer' header when **request.is_secure()**

```
good_referer = 'https://%s/' % request.get_host()
if not same_origin(referer, good_referer):
    reason = REASON_BAD_REFERER % (referer, good_referer)
    return self._reject(request, reason)
```

Comment: what is the solution?